# Запятая перед союзом "и" в наименовании кинофильма

Tags: пунктуация

Недавно в прокат вышла кинолента "Фантастические твари и где они обитают". Возможно, не совсем удачный перевод - логичнее было бы ожидать "Фантастические твари и место / места их обитания". Но имеем, что имеем. Требуется ли в данном случае запятая перед союзом "и", возможно ли как использование, так и неиспользование запятой в зависимости от контекста.

Answer (score 4):

Это разговорная усечённая конструкция от предложения "Фантастические твари и место, где они обитают". Следовательно, первые элементы сложной конструкции - два односоставных назывных предложения в сложносочинённом, объединённые общей интонацией, - запятой нет.

Такие разговорные конструкции с разнотипными частями сложных предложений вообще считаются грамматической ошибкой, а  в художественной литературе используются для придания разговорного характера.В любом случае здесь придаточное предложение употреблено в качестве однородной конструкции, поэтому запятой нет, так как союз не повторяется.

Answer (score 2):

**Фантастические твари и где они обитают**

Одиночный союз И, запятая не нужна.

Обычное явление в русском языке: соединительный  союз И связывает синтаксические единицы разного порядка, в данном случае статус придаточного как бы понижен до слова или словосочетания.

Такие структуры встречаются не только в названиях, но в обычных предложениях, например: На мгновение чуть не позабыли  **Настасью Филипповну и что всё-таки она хозяйка своего вечера.**